# WordPress / Advanced Ads tracking - capping not calculated

Tags: wordpress, cron, ads

I’m working on a multi-site WordPress website which uses Advanced Ads Pro to manage its ads.

I’m facing an issue with the capping option of the plugin. The hourly limits are never calculated, even if the post has:

- An expiration date,
- a print limit
- a click limit
- its status as “published”

[image]

From my understanding, the hourly limit is calculated thanks to the plugin “Advanced Ads – Tracking”. I have noted that removing and reinstalling this plugin will calculate one time only the hourly limit, but not keep it updated.

I tried to reproduce the issue on a new WordPress setup, without success.

When I edit an ad, I would expect an event advanced_ads_tracking_limit_recalculate_pace for the post, but I see none (I have those events on my newly-created test WordPress).

There is nothing interesting in my debug.log file, even with the following properties set to true :

- WP_DEBUG_LOG
- ADVANCED_ADS_TRACKING_CRON_DEBUG